# Why we use country side instead of rural side

Tags: vocabulary

We often compare our rural and urban life. But discussing this matter, we use the city and country life. But why use country life.

We live in a country like Bangladesh. In Bangladesh, there have many rural areas. We can use rural life.

Why we use country life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't two words "country side", but one word - *countryside*. It describes the *land*, not life there. We might say "country life" or "life in the countryside".

The origin of the word *countryside* is apparently that mountains and valleys "divide" land, and so this kind of rural area became known as "countryside" because the land was on one *side* of the valley/mountain or the other.

So "side" is **not** a suffix that means "view", and you can't just add it to another word such as "city". For that, we have the word ***cityscape***, similar to the word *landscape* which can describe almost any scenery.

Comment: -1 for the etymology.